# ZF2 - Zend framework 2, Showing a login template

Tags: zend-framework2

In ZF2 we can set our templates in the Application controller:

```
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../theme/metronic/view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../theme/metronic/view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../theme/metronic/view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../theme/metronic/view/error/index.phtml',
```

This is really useful in terms of code consistency.

My particular template is an administration theme and the login page is completely different from the general layout pages. Obviously I do not want the admin side menus to appear in the login page...

The general pages look like this: http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic_admin&page=index.html

And the login page looks like this: http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic_admin&page=index.html

I have written my Login module however I have no idea how to override the general layout/layout page.

I am still coming to grips with ZF2 routing and I assume all I need to do is enter the correct route to the login template... The other alternative is to put some code in the layout/layout template.phtml file to check if the login url has been accessed and to serve the alternative template. This seems a little messy considering the advanced routing that comes with ZF2.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer and it is relatively simple to install although the documentation is not straightforward.

Thank you to: http://www.webtrafficexchange.com/zf2-configure-layout-each-module-edpmodulelayouts

Basic steps are follows:

1. Clone git clone https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts.git to your Vendor folder
2. Enable in application.config.php:

   'modules' => array(
       'Application',
       'EdpModuleLayouts'
   ),
3. In your application/module.config.php file, add the layouts. This is mine:

   ```
   'view_manager' => array(
   'display_not_found_reason' => true,
   'display_exceptions'       => true,
   'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
   'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
   'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
   'template_map' => array(
       'login/layout'            => __DIR__ . '/../view/login/login.phtml',
       'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
       'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
       'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
       'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
   ),
   'template_path_stack' => array(
       __DIR__ . '/../view',
   ),
   ),

    //Use this to set a custom layout

   'module_layouts' => array(
   'Login' => 'login/layout',
   ),
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add an update to my previous answer. For a simple application EdpModuleLayouts is perfect however there is even a simpler way to change templates that I discovered after the previous answer.

Create a template map as per usual in your Applications module or module of choice:

```
'template_map' => array(
  'login/layout'            => __DIR__ . '/../view/login/login.phtml',
  'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
  'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
  'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
  'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
),
```

Then in the action of the controller, simply use:

```
$this->layout('login/layout');
```

This is not a solution if you are attempting to change the template of a .vendor controller action under composer control.